# Testing IE6 with Firebug Lite

Tags: debugging, testing, internet-explorer-6, firebug-lite, ietester

I'm using IEtester to test in IE6, because the client want the page to be seen in it.

Till a few weeks ago, I could work as good as possible using the firebug lite Stable Channel in IE6 on the IETester. Now I can't! I don't know what changed... and I don't know how to work now, how to test the CSS online etc.

I have tried all the posibilities in `http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable`. Using the live link of each one, using the favorite button and/or downloading the firebug and adding a local link!

Nothing seems to work. Works only when I added this to the head of the page:
`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js'></script>`

But with that version I can't test the CSS live. I need to go to the CSS, write on the right column bla bla... thats the same as going to my own stylesheet page. That is not helping me...=(

I'm getting desperate with the IE6. Do you know a debugbug that I can use to test CSS live in a IE6 Tester?

If you had to work with IE6, how would you be working?

Please SOS me! =(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have asked 5 questions without no up votes and accepted answers, few will be interested to help you much longer if you don't bother appreciating the help you get.

Comment: Not appreciating the help? lol... I dont know what you mean because I appreciated extremelly!=) What have I done wrong? What am I missing? I dont understand... I have just "click" in the ok tilt after the number of the unswer. Is that what you meant???? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try loading older versions of Firebug Lite, like this one which supports live editing of CSS rules:

https://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.3/firebug-lite.js

The best way to get support for problems in Firebug Lite is creating an issue report in our bug tracker:

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone else encounter issues with the styles not being picked up? Half the elements i look at have blank styles. I am only able to edit the styles after manually putting an inline style.

Answer (score 0):

There is only way to do this 100% correctly and that is running a real version of IE6. Get VirtualBox(Free) and install a Virtual Machine with XP running IE6.