# jquery and IE6 how to test problems

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I am having a problem with a jquery on IE6 and I don't know how to check were the problem is. IETester does not seem to have this feature. Is there anything else for testing?

OK I am showing some code that it is supposed to delete staff. This Does Not work in IE6:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
                $(this).next('.loading').fadeIn();

                var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                var string = 'solutionID='+ id;

                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "/js/ajax/delete-comment.php",
                   data: string,
                   cache: false,
                   success: function(){
                    commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                    $('.loading').fadeOut();
                  }

                 });

                return false;
                });
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific than "I am having problems".

Comment: @AaronS: With IE6 it's pretty hard to be more specific.  It's errors don't really help much.

Comment: Try using [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) to help you out.

Comment: It is an ajax jquery script that adds and return results form database. It works everywhere else but IE6. I am just looking for a way to find out where the problem is in IE6.

Comment: @Rocket: However, he can add information such as what he's trying to do, post code that isn't working, etc. There's not much this community can do to help if the only information is "I am having problems"

Comment: the ajax call or the callback doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite):

- [Testing IE6 with Firebug Lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687421/testing-ie6-with-firebug-lite)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can try to find the function where the error appears, with:

```
alert();
```

It's annoying but normally it don't take that much time.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft makes Windows XP VHD images with IE6 installed for testing/debugging purposes; you should try to use that instead.

Also, make sure you install IE Developer toolbar into IE6 once you have the VM up and running; will make debugging much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and it works also in IE for me. I just make some indentions. What exactly is the error you have?

```
$(".delete").click(function(event) {
  var item = $(this),
      commentContainer = item.parent(),
      id = item.attr("id"),
      string = "solutionID=" + id;

  item.next(".loading").fadeIn();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/foo.php",
    data: string,
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
      commentContainer.slideUp("slow", function() {
        item.remove();
        $(".loading").fadeOut();
      });
    }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Demo: http://brbforum.de/stackoverflow_ie6_ajax_test.html

Comment: There no response on button click.

Comment: So the fadein from the loading indicator is not happening?

Comment: Nothing happens. the page just goes up to top

Comment: I amusing IETester, although I have checked it on a real IE6 on xp today and it does not work heither.

Comment: Do you have the same issue with my demo code? If the page goes on top I assume the trigger for delete looks like <a href="#" class="foo">. In this case when the page jumps to # the link observer is not set right.

Comment: Yes same problem with your code. This is the code: <a href="#" id="24" class="delete">DELETE</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can download [scd10en.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22185), the Microsoft Script Debugger. It has the ability to step through scripts, set breakpoints, and run commands from a console.