# JavaFX - How to capture loaded Url in WebEngine

Tags: javafx, javafx-webengine

I use JavaFX WebEngine to render HTML web pages.
I need to measure the loading time of all the images / medias of the page.  I would like to measure the load time for each resource (js, css, image, etc).

I first tried to use URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory() with a custom URLStreamHandler to override the http protocol, but with no success.

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: I deleted my answer showing load time for the whole page and edited your question.  Now, at least, your question will still show as unanswered.

Comment: I know this is not really an answer but I would image there are other, better tools to measure the loading time. Unless you're specifically comparing JavaFX's WebEngine's performance, I would avoid digging into that library because as of now it is not very rich on features to allow you to do these things. The key goal of the developers must've been simplification, as loading a page is real easy, but there are almost no debugging options.

Comment: Alternatively, I've seen a question on SO somewhere (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387981/javafx-webview-webengine-firebuglite-or-some-other-debugger) about the possibility to inject a JS debugger, like FireBug, which you can then use to do some debugging. Not fit for production code, but might do the trick for you.