# Firebug Lite + Bootstrap doesn't work with Firebug Lite version 1.3 and beyond

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firebug-lite

I've added Firebug Lite to a JavaFX Webview (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387981/javafx-webview-webengine-firebuglite-or-some-other-debugger) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398879/html-javascript-debugging-in-javafx-webview)).
That works well until I add bootstrap.css.
I've tried different versions of Firebug Lite, and it seems it's ok until version 1.2. Something changed with version 1.3 that prevents Firebug Lite from working. Its div/frame doesn't appear. I've also tried loading the same page on standard browsers, same result.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried the latest debug version and that works for me

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/latest/firebug-lite-debug.js'></script>
```