# DukeScript, why using @JavaScriptResource rather than importing a js resource with <script>?

Tags: jquery, dukescript

Quote from [Using the Knockout API](https://dukescript.com/knockout4j.html)

> Define a class JQuery and add the JavaScript-library to your project.
>   Now you can reference it using @JavaScriptResource. This is how you
>   manage JavaScript libraries in DukeScript

Is that any different from including a javascript file with the `<script>` tag inside an html page?
I've tried both and couldn't see why using the annotation @JavaScriptResouce would be any different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea of @JavaScriptRessource is to use it for defining your own Java API over a javascript library, e.g. the API for knockout.

With "script" it would be the users responsibility to provide the correct version. With @JSR the user of the API doesn't have to know anything about the required JS-file. Instead you deliver the correct version with the API. The user of the API only has to deal with Java.

If you use JS only for styling&layout (e.g. bootstrap, etc.) it's fine to just add it via "script" tag.

Comment: Thanks @eppleton! So, no magic behind the scenes at this stage from using @JavaScriptRessource, like automatic mapping of javascript APIs into Java :-)